# np.sum for row axis not working in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning, softmax

I wrote a softmax regression function `def softmax_1(x)` that essentially takes in a `m x n` matrix, exponentiates the matrix, then sums the exponentials of each column.

```
x = np.arange(-2.0, 6.0, 0.1)
scores = np.vstack([x, np.ones_like(x), 0.2 * np.ones_like(x)])
#scores shape is (3, 80)

def softmax_1(x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    return(np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x),axis=0))
```

Converting it into a DataFrame I have to transpose

```
DF_activation_1 = pd.DataFrame(softmax_1(scores).T,index=x,columns=["x","1.0","0.2"])
```

So I wanted to try and make a version of the softmax function that takes in the transposed version and computes the softmax function

```
scores_T = scores.T
#scores_T shape is (80,3)

def softmax_2(y):
    return(np.exp(y/np.sum(np.exp(y),axis=1)))

DF_activation_2 = pd.DataFrame(softmax_2(scores_T),index=x,columns=["x","1.0","0.2"])
```

Then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "softmax.py", line 22, in <module>
    DF_activation_2 = pd.DataFrame(softmax_2(scores_T),index=x,columns=["x","1.0","0.2"])
  File "softmax.py", line 18, in softmax_2
    return(np.exp(y/np.sum(np.exp(y),axis=1)))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (80,3) (80,)
```

Why doesn't this work when I transpose and switch the axis in the `np.sum` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
np.exp(y/np.sum(np.exp(y),axis=1))
```

to

```
np.exp(y)/np.sum(np.exp(y),axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

This will mean that `np.sum` will return an array of shape `(80, 1)` rather than `(80,)`, which will broadcast correctly for the division. Also note the correction to the bracket closing.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response, why do my rows not sum to 1 anymore after transposing? First row of `DF_activation_1` is `0.033211  0.667060  0.299729` while first row of `DF_activation_2` is `0.612139  1.278129  1.050304`

Comment: I will mess around with it, the are still summing to > 1. I will let you know when I figure it out.

Comment: Moved comment about brackets accidentally posted as a separate answer below into the answer above.